# How to login to Instagram from codebehind?

Tags: c#, restful-authentication, instagram

I need to show images of a specific instagram user on my webpage.

As stated in the Instagram API documentation I need to get authenticated to be able to "browse" a user's feed.

*"We only require authentication in cases where your application is making requests on behalf of a user (commenting, liking, browsing a user’s feed, etc.)."
(http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/)*

So as stated in the API documentation, I send a request to this URL:

```
https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?display=touch&client_id=[ClientID]
&redirect_uri=[callbackuri]/&response_type=token
```

to be redirected to another URL: `http://your_redirect_uri?code=CODE` to be able to get the access_token (CODE) to be able to call the instagram RESTful services with it.

The problem is that if my website visitor is not logged in to Instagram, he/she will be forwarded to a login page to authenticate first and only then I can get an access token.

My question is: how can I bypass this login page by automatically login with my application's instagram account from the codebehind (or probably by javascript!)?

I am using C# and Instasharp(http://instasharp.org/) by the way.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

first of create Developer app in Instagram and get consumerkey & consumersecret and set path call back url somthing link http://localhost:3104/Instagram.aspx

```
private void Authentication()
    {
        string rest = string.Empty;
        GlobusInstagramLib.Authentication.ConfigurationIns config = new GlobusInstagramLib.Authentication.ConfigurationIns("https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["consumerKey"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["consumerSecret"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["callbackurl"], "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token", "https://api.instagram.com/v1/", "");
        oAuthInstagram _api = oAuthInstagram.GetInstance(config);
        rest = _api.AuthGetUrl("likes+comments+basic+relationships");
        Response.Redirect(rest);
    }
```

Automatic redirect on this page and call this code

```
   public void Instagram()
   {
    string code = (String)Request.QueryString["code"];
    oAuthInstagram objInsta = new oAuthInstagram();
    GlobusInstagramLib.Authentication.ConfigurationIns configi = new GlobusInstagramLib.Authentication.ConfigurationIns("https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["consumerKey"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["consumerSecret"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["callbackurl"], "http://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token", "https://api.instagram.com/v1/", "");
    oAuthInstagram _api = new oAuthInstagram();
    _api = oAuthInstagram.GetInstance(configi);
    AccessToken access = new AccessToken();
    access = _api.AuthGetAccessToken(code);
    string accessToken = access.access_token;
    string id =access.user.id;

   }
```

you will get token and user id